# How to backup local storage data

Tags: cordova, backup, local-storage

We are developing a HTML 5 phonegap app and are using local-storage to persist application data. This works fine. However...how do we backup this data? If the device is reset the local storage will be lost. Is it included when I backup my iPhone (using iTunus) and are there android apps that can provide backup functionality? Or should we provide a server-side for our application...

Comment: Is it losing the data after a soft reset?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind you already mentioned: A remote database on a server.

Comment: No data is lost after soft reset. But for example one might lose the device. It would be nice to copy localstorage onto a replacing device

Comment: Seams your localstorage may be lost on app updates from the store...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local storage should *only* be used as a cache or for data that doesn't *need* to be persisted across sessions. If it is, cool, but it should not be relied upon.

Instead, you should be persisting any required data back to your server and using local storage simply as a client-side cache.

To "back up" stuff already *in* local storage, simply read it out and persist it back to your server.

Comment: Why not rely upon local storage accross sessions? Is it not guaranteed to be persisted?

Comment: The problem with local storage is that you, the developer, don't have control over the data, so if the user screws something up, you can't help them out and they just get pissed of. Having control over the data is _much_ more reliable.